# Meaning of "mulling a factory"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

> A Japanese newspaper partly held by Toyota reported a month later that
>   the carmaker was mulling a factory in Brazil for production of the
>   same car.

[[Source](http://uk.reuters.com/article/toyota-india-idUKNOA33088820070213)]

I couldn't find a phrase 'mulling a factory' in any dictionary, hence I instead searched 'mull' in Merriam-Webster.

> 1. to grind or mix thoroughly
> 2. to consider at length :   ponder —often used with over

I guess the meaning of 'mulling a factory' is 'founding or making a new factory', which has nothing to do with the meaning of 'mull'.

Is my guess correct? If it is, is 'mulling a factory' a common or natural expression?

Can you help me understand the phrase 'mulling a factory'?

Comment: It's definition 2 that you have posted.  Toyota is considering whether building a factory in Brazil will be profitable enough to be worth the expense.

Comment: What Toyota is mulling (considering at length) is where to build the car, Bangalore or Brazil or elsewhere. The context in the article makes this clear, sort of.

Comment: Either they stuck a red-hot piece of iron into a factory or they're considering building one.

Answer (score 1):

"Mulling a factory" is not an idiom of English.

The meaning is "considering at length *the possibility of setting up* a factory.

Comment: ODO for [mull](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mull) shows an example sentence without the usual *over*.

Comment: I've heard it only in the form "mulling over" in this context. (agreeing with @AndrewLeach)